# How to receive python's array in function

Tags: python, function, numpy, parameter-passing

How do I receive an array (like numpy ones) into a function? Let's say the array `a = [[2],[3]]` and the function `f`. Tuples works like this:

```
def f((a ,b)):
    print a * b

f((2,3))
```

But how is it with arrays?

```
def f(#here):
    print a*b

f([[2],[3]])
```

Comment: As a side note, the form of the first function is a `SyntaxError` in python3.x.  I would advise moving away from using that construct.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I've been far from python's news hehe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuple unpacking in function arguments has been removed from Python 3, so I suggest you stop using it.

Lists can be unpacked just like tuples:

```
def f(arg):
    [[a], [b]] = arg

    return a * b
```

Or as a tuple:

```
((x,), (y,)) = a
```

But I would just use indexes:

```
return arg[0][0] * arg[1][0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the unpacking advice. @mgilson wrote it below the question but both were helpful. I use a and b because the goal is to be clear in the code (a and b has their meaning in a context).